# An error occurred translating the connection string to UTF-16 in PHP SQL server

Tags: php, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using PHP 5.2.9 and Micorsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 with Apache, and have a PHP line of code like this

```
<?php
$serverName = "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\xxx"
$connection = array("Database"=>"example");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connection);

if( $conn )
{
     echo "Connection established.";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.";
         print_r($connection);
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

but it shows error like this:

> `Connection could not be established.
>
>
>
> Array ( [Database] => example )
>
>
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -47 [code] => -47 [2] => An error occurred translating the connection string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. [message] => An error occurred translating the connection string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. ) )`

Any sugestion for my problem?

Comment: Looks like the `$serverName` value may have a bad escape sequence. Try single quotes `$serverName = 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\xxx'`

Comment: i've try use single quote, but the error change to server not found. i'm sure that the error is in the $connection, but i don't know what to do. i've try using iconv() to some unicode, but still not work.